# Panels modules got rid of all my pages

Tags: routes, panels

I recently installed a theme that called for [Panels Everywhere](https://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere), [Mini Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels_mini_ipe), and [Page Manage](https://drupal.org/project/ctools)r modules to be installed.  The theme looks great but I don't understand where all my custom pages went?

I had created a bunch of pages in my custom module using `hook_menu()`.  Now my site is completely driven by Panels and Page Manager.  I assume all my `MENU_NORMAL_ITEMS` were being stored in a block that is now being suppressed by panels everywhere.

How do I get all my old menu items to work with my new theme?  How do I link up the elements of my theme with my existing pages?

Answer (score 2):

Panels everywhere is like it says, a way to use Panels all over your site. This means that whats normally outputted by `page.tpl.php` will now be run through a Panel.

Enable the site template (if not already done) here: `/admin/structure/pages`
Edit the site template and add the page elements as you want your site to be built. Eg. add the site header, then the page title, page content etc.

There is also a setting to create a sample site template variant for you here `/admin/structure/panels/settings/everywhere`.

Comment: Where are the pages that I created in hook_menu() in my custom modules?  I though I'd be able to find them at `admin/structure/pages` but I cannot.

Comment: No, all your own items you added in hook_menu are still just menu items and not panels. You will have to recreate them in Panels (give them a path, choose layout, place panes).